# Django restframework can't get post data with a multipart parser

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, file-upload

i am trying to save an object with an image using django restframework but when i use the FormParser and MultiPartParser classes the request.data object get seemingly encoded msgs and when i try to decode using utf-8 it outputs an error saying this data is not utf-8

i want to have access to the request.data data and be able to save the image for future requests

here is my view function:

```
@parser_classes([FormParser, MultiPartParser])
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def products(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.data)

        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        serializer.initial_data['user'] = request.user.pk

        serializer.initial_data['price'] = float(
            request.data['price'])

        serializer.initial_data['quantity'] = int(
            request.data['quantity'])

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': "product added"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my front end code:

```
export const addProduct = async (product) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("name", product.name);
    fd.append("price", product.price);
    fd.append("quantity", product.quantity);
    fd.append("image_url", product.image_url);

    console.log(product.image_url) //this prints a file object

    const response = await fetch(`${URL}/products`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${fd._boundary}`,
        },
        body: fd,
    })
    return response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image data is not being encoded as UTF-8 (Maybe! and if so), you can use the FileField or ImageField field in your serializer, along with the FormParser and MultiPartParser classes!

[UPDATED] Your view should be:

```
@parser_classes([FormParser, MultiPartParser])
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def products(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.initial_data['user'] = request.user.pk

        if 'price' in request.data:
            serializer.initial_data['price'] = float(request.data['price'])
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'price not found in request data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if 'quantity' in request.data:
            serializer.initial_data['quantity'] = int(request.data['quantity'])
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'quantity not found in request data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': "product added"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And the serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.ImageField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'quantity', 'image_url', 'user']
```

Comment: i have added the serializer line and i still get the same erros

Comment: this is the last error i got django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'price'

Comment: and do i encode the image in the front end and if so how do i do it?

Comment: You do not need to encode the image in the frontend! The FormData automatically handles encoding binary data (such as an image file), so you can simply append the image file to the FormData object and send it in the request body as-is.

Comment: And the error occurs because the key 'price' is not found in the request data.. I have updated my answer (check the view code and replace it)

Comment: In the updated code, I just added a check to see if the price is in request.data and if not it will return an error response

Answer (score 0):

so when i removed my headers it worked fine, so apparently if you choose to use multipart/form-data, the boundary must not appear in the file data that the server eventually receives.

The problem with multipart/form-data is that the boundary separator must not be present in the file data (see RFC 2388; section 5.2 also includes a rather lame excuse for not having a proper aggregate MIME type that avoids this problem).

so i fixed it by removing the boundary in the front end which makes my frontend code look something like this

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("name", product.name);
fd.append("price", product.price);
fd.append("quantity", product.quantity);
fd.append("image_url", product.image_url);

console.log(product.image_url) // this print a File object

const response = await fetch(`${URL}/products`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${localStorage.getItem("auth")}`
    },
    body: fd,
})
```